# Multiple DataSource beans with Spring Boot Actuator's EndpointAutoConfiguration possible?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application that uses several `DataSource` beans and would still like to use the `EndpointAutoConfiguration` from spring-boot-actuator that is loaded as part of using the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.  This doesn't seem possible as there is a `DataSource` bean injected into `EndpointAutoConfiguration` to setup the `HealthEndpoint` bean.  Due to the multiple instances of `DataSource` that exist in my application, a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` is thrown upon application startup unless I exclude `EndpointAutoConfiguration` but then I must setup all the other endpoints manually (/env, /metrics, etc).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark one of your `DataSources` as `@Primary` or you could provide your own `HealthIndicator` (it's not the endpoint that wants your `DataSource` but that bean, which is designed to be overridden by just adding one of your own).

Comment: Hi, Dave. I am already configuring my own `HealthIndicator`. However, the exception is still thrown due to the `DataSource` being `@Autowired` on line 78 of `EndpointAutoConfiguration`. It seems that marking one as `@Primary` is the only way to do this without a code change to Spring Boot, correct?

Comment: Correct. If you'd like to make that change go ahead. `@Primary` shouldn't have any side effects to an app that already works with 2 `DataSources` though.

Comment: Ok, no problem.  `@Primary` does not cause any side effects.  Would the project be interested in a `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` that instantiates the `HealthIndicator` as it's being done now in `EndpointAutoConfiguration`?  This would allow someone in my position to simply exclude that class in the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.  If you think it'd be accepted, I'll go ahead and submit the pull request.

Comment: The project would be interested. But IMO it's probably better just to make it a nested class inside the `EndpointAutoConfuguration`, and I would prefer to use a `@Conditional` to exclude it and/or use all available `DataSources` in the existing health indicator.